# divide $12$ different candies among $5$ different kids (with restrictions)

Tags: combinatorics

There are multiple variations to similar question but this one is somehow special ;-) and I need confirmation that my approach is correct (or wrong). So,

> In how many ways we can divide (distribute) $12$ different (distinct) candies among $5$ kids (some of them can get none) and one of them specifically (let's say) George Constanza has to get at least one candy?

So any (first) of $12$ candies is given to George and we can do that in $12$ possible ways.

Now we have $11$ candies to divide among George and $4$ another kids ($5$ in total).

So candy no.2 we can give to $5$ different kids, candy no.3 to $5$ different kids... candy no. 11 to $5$ diff. kids.
And finally solution would be $12 \cdot 5^{11}$?

Am I right?

Comment: No...this overcounts, as there is no way to distinguish the candy you give George initially from the ones you give him subsequently (if any).

Comment: Find the number of ways to distribute without restriction, then subtract the number of ways that violate the restriction (the number of ways in which George gets no candies, which is the number of ways to distribute the candies to the other four kids.

Comment: Hint for an alternate approach:  Count the ways you do it while ignoring the constraint on George.  Now subtract off the ways in which George gets $0$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You are overcounting. Suppose you have $2$ candies and $2$ people: George and Elaine. Your method says that there are $2$ ways to give George one candy, after which the second candy can be given to either George or Elaine, so that's $2 \cdot 2 = 4$ ways. However, there are only $3$ ways to do this: George gets candy 1 and Elaine gets candy 2, or vice versa, or George gets both candies. Indeed, it is the situation of George getting both candies that you are counting twice.

Answer (score 0):

> In how many ways can $12$ different candies be distributed to $5$ children if one of those children must receive at least one candy?

If we ignore the restriction, there are $5$ ways to distribute each of the $12$ candies, so we could distribute the candies in $5^{12}$ ways.  From these, as Daniel Mathias and lulu indicated in the comments, we must subtract the number of ways of distributing the candies in which that particular child receives no candies.  Since the $12$ candies could be distributed to the remaining $4$ children in $4^{12}$ ways, the number of ways the $12$ different candies could be distributed to the five children if one particular child must receive at least one candy is $5^{12} - 4^{12}$.

*Why is your answer incorrect?*

There are $\binom{12}{k}$ to give that child exactly $k$ of the candies and $4^{12 - k}$ ways to distribute the remaining candies to the remaining children.  Therefore, the number of ways of distributing the candies so that particular child receives at least one candy is 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^{12} \binom{12}{k}4^{12 - k} & = -4^{12} + \sum_{k = 0}^{12} \binom{12}{k}4^{12 - k}\\ 
& = -4^{12} + \sum_{k = 0}^{12} \binom{12}{12 - k}4^{12 - k}\\
& = -4^{12} + \sum_{j = 0}^{12} \binom{12}{j}4^j && \text{set $j = 12 - k$}\\
& = -4^{12} + \sum_{j = 0}^{12} \binom{12}{j}1^{12 - j}4^j\\
& = -4^{12} + (1 + 4)^{12} && \text{by the Binomial Theorem}\\
& = -4^{12} + 5^{12}\\
& = 5^{12} - 4^{12}
\end{align*}
By designating a particular candy as being the candy that child receives, you count each distribution in which that child receives exactly $k$ candies $k$ times, once for each way you could designate one of those candies as being the one that child receives.  Notice that 
$$\color{red}{12 \cdot 5^{11}} = \sum_{k = 1}^{12} \color{red}{k}\binom{12}{k}4^{12 - k}$$
since
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^{12} k\binom{12}{k}4^{12 - k} & = \sum_{k = 1}^{12} k \cdot \frac{12!}{k!(12 - k)!}4^{12 - k}\\
& = \sum_{k = 1}^{12} \frac{12!}{(k - 1)!(12 - k)!}4^{12 - k}\\
& = 12\sum_{k = 1}^{12} \frac{11!}{(k - 1)!(12 - k)!}4^{12 - k}\\
& = 12\sum_{k = 1}^{12} \frac{11!}{(k - 1)![11 - (k - 1)]!}4^{11 - (k - 1)}\\
& = 12\sum_{j = 0}^{11} \frac{11!}{j!(11 - j)!}4^{11 - j}  && \text{set $j = k - 1$}\\
& = 12\sum_{j = 0}^{11} \binom{11}{j}4^{11 - j}\\
& = 12\sum_{j = 0}^{11} \binom{11}{11 - j}4^{11 - j}\\
& = 12\sum_{\ell = 0}^{11} \binom{11}{\ell}4^{\ell} && \text{set $\ell = 11 - j$}\\
& = 12\sum_{\ell = 0}^{11} \binom{11}{\ell}1^{11 - \ell}4^{\ell}\\
& = 12(1 + 4)^{11} && \text{by the Binomial Theorem}\\
& = 12 \cdot 5^{11}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

> In how many ways can $12$ different candies be distributed to $5$ children if one of those children must receive at least one candy?

Think of a case where you give *nothing* to George Constanza and distribute all the 12 distinct candies to the rest of the 4 kids, zeroes allowed. This can be done in 
$4^{12}$ ways.

Add all the cases from this problem, and you should have all the possible ways to distribute the 12 distinct candies, zeroes allowed. This is $5^{12}$ ways.

Thus our solution is $5^{12} - 4^{12}$ ways.